# Row ID is undefined for new added row in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I think this is a repeated question, but I see all the answers and nothing clear?
I used data tables in my MVC app and everything works perfectly, till I add a new row to this datatable using

```
table.api().row.add
```

after that, I assigned row id using two methods then draw
1-

```
row.nodes().to$().attr('id', ID)
```

2-

```
row.node().id = ID
```

When I try to get the newly added row id using row.id its undefined and row.data not contain dt_rowid at all.
In HTML I can see the id correctly added
How to get the id for the newly added row
Please help me

Comment: You want ur id when u click on table row correct? can u post html code?

Comment: i need to get row id on rows every in datatables not on click

Comment: Than u need to get all new rowid or only newly added row id?

Comment: I have function that loop through rows , and this function loop on new and old rows to get row id then make updates

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.rows().every(function () {
var data = this.data();
var id = this.id();
console.log('Data id: ' + id);
});
```

Try this. Please refer this link
https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()